# Eclipse Tomcat Error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to run a dynamic web project in Eclipse on Tomcat Server. However I get the error **The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.** when running the project. The name of the project is **DBAccess**.

My web.xml is located under **WebContent\WEB-INF** in my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>DBAccess</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>acessor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>dbaccess.servlet.DatabaseAccessor</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>acessor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DBAccess/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My servlet class is located under **src\dbaccess\servlet** in my project.

```
package dbaccess.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class DBAccessorServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -134532546577657L;

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            System.out.println("The GET");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            System.out.println("The POST");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            System.out.println("The PUT");
        }

    }
```

What should I do in order to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`<servlet-class>dbaccess.servlet.DatabaseAccessor</servlet-class>` should be  changed to `<servlet-class>dbaccess.servlet.DBAccessorServlet</servlet-class>` at least.

Comment: Whoops! Missed that typo in my code. I fixed it but am still getting the same error though.





**<servlet>
   <servlet-name>accessor</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>dbaccess.servlet.DBAccessorServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>accessor</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/DBAccess/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>**

Comment: Is `DBAccessorServlet.class` in WEB-INF/classes/dbaccess/servlet/?